# NODE – exclude from tree (Node Wrangler)

Tags: node-editor

In Blender I can simply exclude node from a node tree with Alt+RMB, but with "Node Wrangler" addon the "Alt" key is used for Mix node.

How can I exclude node from tree with "Node Wrangler" enabled?
Thanks

[image]
Another example – that I can't do with Wrangler enabled.
[image]

Comment: I use `Ctrl` + `LMB` and draw a circle around the node.

Comment: ... but you loose a string. You have to reconnect it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - detach node from all inputs and outputs

[image]

(Works in blender 2.79 or 2.8x as default function, no conflict with Node Wrangler if enabled.)

Answer (score 1):

There is *Detach From Outputs* function which does that, also leaving inputs of the node you moved out from the tree attached. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> with node to detach:

[image: gif-image]

Or from the Node Wrangler toolshelf (<kbd>N</kbd> in the UV editor, *Node Wrangler* tab):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help. If this is the addons way I will try to remap shortcuts.